# Magento get email template by code

Tags: templates, magento

I have created an email template for a custom module, placed the file in `app/locale/en_US/template/email` and configured it in my module config XML file. Now I want to retrieve that template in a controller through code. I have tried :

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('custom_template');
```

But it returns a `NULL` email template. My module email template config is :

```
<global>
    <template>
        <email>
            <custom_template>
                <label>Some custom email template</label>
                <file>custom_template.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </custom_template>
        </email>
    </template>
</global>
```

What am I missing?

** **Edit** **

I have found [this](http://blog.decryptweb.com/email-templates-in-magento/) code, but the line

```
$template_collection =  Mage::getResourceSingleton('core/email_template_collection');
```

returns an empty collection. I tried to look into into Magento's admin source and found `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Email_Template_Grid` which *also* uses the same line to get a collection and, apparently, it works for Magento, but not with my code. Why?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The PHP you posted

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('custom_template');
```

will load an email template **from the database**. Specifically, from the `core_email_template` table.  The template you've placed on the file system is the default template.  You should be able to load it using the `loadDefault` method.

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('custom_template');
```

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is looking for full sample code of how to send a Magento email based on an existing Magento email template, the following works well. It does not require any XML config.

```
// This is the name that you gave to the template in System -> Transactional Emails
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('My Custom Email Template');

// These variables can be used in the template file by doing {{ var some_custom_variable }}
$emailTemplateVariables = array(
'some_custom_variable' => 'Hello World'
);

$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

$emailTemplate->setSenderName('Joe Bloggs');
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('test@test.com');
$emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject("Here is your subject");

$emailTemplate->send('recipient@test.com', 'Joanna Bloggs', $emailTemplateVariables);
```